# Are users and permissions set by Visual SVN server valid also for apache?

Tags: apache, permissions, visualsvn-server

I have succeeded in setting users and permissions of a repository by editing the "authz" file used by VisualSVN Server manager.
Are these changes still valid if I start managing the repository by Apache?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what exactly you ask about.

Comment: If I set the authentication data of a repository using VisualSVN Server manager, but then I start managing the server of the repository using Apache, are these authentication data "valid" also for Apache or I should set them again?

Comment: I mean if I set the authentication data using SVN Server Manager, are these data stored in the repository or somewhere in SVN Server Manager? In the second case, I should set them again when I stop using SVN Server Manager and I start usign Apache. In the former case, instead, I should be sure that the wa SVN Server set these data is valid also for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN Server stores access rules in per-repository files `/conf/VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini` or `/conf/VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini` (depends on the authorization and authentication type selected in VisualSVN Server: Windows (Active Directory) or Subversion). For Windows (Active Directory) authz and auth, there is also `VisualSVN-GlobalWinAuthz.ini` file at the root directory with your repositories (`C:\Repositories`, by default).

Generally speaking, these are [common path-based authz files](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html). But to be able to use them with another server package (i.e. not VisualSVN Server), you should configure the server package accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)